# Choropleth map with R using shp file

Tags: r, dictionary, ggplot2, gis

Hello stackoverflow community!

Could someone kindly please assist me as I am having some difficulties with creating a choropleth map in R. As of now, I have assigned LL information to my points of interest, and I now want to create a choropleth map using the "cans" variable in the dataset (data.csv) by high school district area (highdist_n83.shp.zip). What I would like to please know is how to properly fill the map with the sum of cans per district area. I have provided code, which pulls a sample datafile from dropbox and the shape file I would like to use.

**EDIT**
Sorry, I forgot to add that when I plot just the shape file, I am able to see it rendered via ggplot. However, when I try to "fill" the districts using the number of "cans" variable, R hangs for awhile before rendering what appears to be a mass of lines over the original shape. I wonder if the error is due to the following possible reasons

1. the shape file is not good
2. there may be an issue with how I am merging the data frame and the shape file as I've noticed additional rows are added to the merged file
3. there are multiple schools in an area, which I haven't combined when using ddply.

Thank you for your time!

```
###load R scripts from dropbox
dropbox.eval <- function(x, noeval=F) {
require(RCurl)
intext <- getURL(paste0("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/",x), ssl.verifypeer = FALSE)
intext <- gsub("\r","", intext)
if (!noeval) eval(parse(text = intext), envir= .GlobalEnv)
return(intext)
}

##pull scripts from dropbox 
dropbox.eval("s/wgb3vtd9qfc9br9/pkg.load.r")    
dropbox.eval("s/tf4ni48hf6oh2ou/dropbox.r")

##load packages
pkg.load(c(ggplot2,plyr,gdata,sp,maptools,rgdal,reshape2))

###setup data frames
dl_from_dropbox("data.csv","dx3qrcexmi9kagx")
    data<-read.csv(file='data.csv',header=TRUE)

###prepare GIS shape and data for plotting
dropbox.eval("s/y2jsx3dditjucxu/dlshape.r")     
temp <- tempfile()
dlshape(shploc="http://files.hawaii.gov/dbedt/op/gis/data/highdist_n83.shp.zip", temp)
shape<- readOGR(".","highdist_n83") #HDOE high school districts  
shape@proj4string 

shape2<- spTransform(shape, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=NAD83"))

data.2<-ddply(data, .(year, schoolcode, longitude, latitude,NAME,HDist,SDist), summarise,
        total = sum(total),
        cans= sum(cans))

coordinates(data.2) <-~longitude + latitude
shape2.df<-fortify(shape2)
mshape2.df<- merge(shape2.df,shape2@data, by.x="id", by.y="ID",all=TRUE)

newdata <- merge(mshape2.df,data.2, by.x="NAME", by.y="NAME", all=TRUE)
newdata  <- newdata [order(newdata $order),]

###choropleth map: 
mapPlot <- ggplot(newdata,aes(x=long, y=lat,drop=FALSE)) +
geom_polygon(aes(fill=cans, drop=FALSE), colour = "black", lwd = 1/9,na.rm=FALSE)
+ ggtitle("Total of Cans Across State")
print(mapPlot)
```

Comment: Thank you for the code. Before we start, can you tell us specifically what the problem is and/or include a screenshot. Do you get a warning message, or does it not plot or is the plot wrong? etc etc

Comment: Hi SlowLearner. I've edited my original message to describe the issue I am experiencing. It is quite long, but I hope it might clear up what I need help with. After running ggplot code, R basically hangs for awhile before rendering what looks to be a massive number of lines over the shape file. I've listed some possible issues, but then again I am a complete novice at this stuff... Thank you again for your time! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you fortify your shapefile you end up with the wrong IDs. Instead, explicitly add an ID column based on the row names of the shapefile and use this to merge. You also do not tell `geom_polygon` how to group the rows in your `data.frame` so they are all plotted as one continuous overlapping, self-intersecting polygon. Add a group argument to `geom_polygon`. I also like to use `RColorBrewer` to pick nice colours for maps (using the function `brewer.pal`).

Try this:

```
require(RColorBrewer)
shape2@data$id <- rownames(shape2@data)
sh.df <- as.data.frame(shape2)
sh.fort <- fortify(shape2 , region = "id" )
sh.line<- join(sh.fort, sh.df , by = "id" )


mapdf <- merge( sh.line , data.2 , by.x= "NAME", by.y="NAME" , all=TRUE)
mapdf <- mapdf[ order( mapdf$order ) , ]

ggplot( mapdf , aes( long , lat ) )+
  geom_polygon( aes( fill = cans , group = id ) , colour = "black" )+
  scale_fill_gradientn( colours = brewer.pal( 9 , "Reds" ) )+
  coord_equal()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I would have never figured it out without your help! It worked perfectly, and the RColorBrewer package is a huge improvement visually.

Comment: @user2434624 I'm glad this helped you. Yes the `ColorBrewer` package is great!

Comment: Sorry, this just popped up in my head... I'm not sure if this requires asking a new question, but how can I turn the fortified/merged file back into a shape file? Specifically, I would like to write it out as GeoJSON data using the writeOGR() function...

Comment: This would be a new question.

Comment: Thank for your solution. It works well but the use of the option `region` in the `sh.fort <- fortify(shape2 , region = "id" )` can generate the following error : `Error: isTRUE(gpclibPermitStatus()) is not TRUE`. Look at this question to solve this problem : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21125942/converting-spatial-polygon-to-regular-data-frame-without-use-of-gpclib-tools/21126558#21126558)