# Converting spatial polygon to regular data frame without use of gpclib tools

Tags: r, ggplot2, gis, r-s4, r-maptools

I working with spatial data in R for a commercial application and would like to use ggplot2 for data visualization. If you run the Hadley's example at https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/plotting-polygon-shapefiles you find that in order to run the `fortify` command you need to enable the use of gpclib tools using `gpclibPermit()`.

I'm looking for an efficient way (that doesn't involve manually hacking into the S4 object) to perform the same operation that `fortify` does here, i.e. take a spatial polygon object and turn it into a regular data frame where row entries contain latitudinal and longitudinal coordinates along with a polygon id.

Has anyone else solved this one?

Comment: I'm probably not understanding your question, but I use `fortify(...)` all the time and have never had to use gpclibPermot(...).

Comment: have you checked the example that i posted? when i run it the error `Error: isTRUE(gpclibPermitStatus()) is not TRUE` gets thrown up. it may be that fortify works fine for some sp objects and not for others...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to also install the `rgeos` package. When `maptools` is loaded and `rgeos` is not installed, the following message is shown:

```
> require("maptools")
Loading required package: maptools
Checking rgeos availability: FALSE
    Note: when rgeos is not available, polygon geometry
    computations in maptools depend on gpclib,
    which has a restricted licence. It is disabled by default;
    to enable gpclib, type gpclibPermit()
```

When `fortify` is called with a `region` argument (as it is in the example you linked to), then some "polygon geometry computations" need to be done. If `rgeos` is not available, and `gpclib` is not permitted, it will fail.

Comment: I'm seeing the same message when I tried to use maptools for the first time. Am I correct in understanding that I need  EITHER (1) rgeos or (2) enabled gpclib? Does the latter come with a non-commercial license or something? Between rgeos and gpclib, which is better (faster, better results, etc.)?

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 Correct; you need one or the other, and since `gpclib` had a [license that does not allow for commercial use](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gpclib/LICENSE), there is the extra safety step of requiring an explicit function call to enable it.

Comment: @BrianDiggs: is there any difference between them in terms of results or performance?

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 I don't have any information about results or performance either way.

Comment: same here in 2016.. having got that message and not implementing commercial software, which of the two packages is better supported/ more commonly used?