# gpclibPermit() not working

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, rgdal

I cannot use functions from packages to do maps on R as I cannot find a way to enable gpclibPermit().

I have read the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21093399/how-to-turn-gpclibpermit-to-true) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30790036/error-istruegpclibpermitstatus-is-not-true). but not luck.

I have installed and run successfully the following packages:

- maptools
- ggplot2
- (c("sp", "maptools"))
- rgeos
- rgda
- gpclib

And yet I keep getting the message:

gpclibPermit()
FALSE

gpclibPermitStatus()
FALSE

What am I doing wrong?! I also updated all my packages (successfully)...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unless someone has a better answer, I think I found my explanation [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/86793/what-is-the-latest-version-of-r-that-supported-gpclib):

Whilst R told me that the package gclib was somehow installed, it looks like it wouldn't work as new versions of R do not support this package (apparently it used to crash the system etc.) rgeos is suggested elsewhere as a suitable alternative.

Hope this helps other newbies of mapping in R like myself.

Cheers

Comment: Newbies in mapping with R ask question here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/r

Comment: i'm up against the same problem. How do you use rgeos as an alternative?