# simplify my us state shapefile with rmapshaper::ms_simplify gives error

Tags: r, gis, shapefile, r-leaflet, tigris

I'm making chloropleth us state map on my shiny app using leaflet package. I found rendering the map is very slow. After googling , it seems like maybe the shapefile is too complex and simplifying that might make it a lot faster. According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44068225/shiny-app-that-generates-leaflet-map-out-of-a-shapefile-and-csv-too-slow-crashe), simplifying the shapefile might be the answer.

Reading shape file works OK. I was able to render my leaflet map.

```
states_shape <- tigris::states(cb = TRUE, resolution='500k')
leaflet(states_shape) %>%
  addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>%
  addPolygons(fillColor = "white",
              color = "black",
              weight = 0.5) %>%
  setView(-98.5795, 39.8282, zoom=3)
```

I tried to simplify my shapefile with `rmapshaper::ms_simplify`

```
states_shape_simple <- rmapshaper::ms_simplify(states_shape, keep = 0.05, keep_shapes = TRUE)
```

I got error like below:

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : isTRUE(gpclibPermitStatus()) is not TRUE
```

I have no idea what that mean and what to do.  Does anyone know why that happened and how to make it work? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi! Can you try running `tigris::states()` setting `class = "sf"` and then `rmapshaper::ms_simplify()`?

Comment: it works!  Please put it as the answer and I will accept it.    btw, what's the diff between 'sp' and 'sf'? why it works with class='sf'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```r
# packages
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.8.0, GDAL 3.0.4, PROJ 6.3.1
library(leaflet)

# data
states_shape <- tigris::states(cb = TRUE, resolution='500k', class = "sf")

# simplify
states_shape_simple <- rmapshaper::ms_simplify(states_shape, keep = 0.05, keep_shapes = TRUE)
states_shape_simple <- st_transform(states_shape_simple, 4326)

# plot
leaflet(states_shape_simple) %>%
  addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>%
  addPolygons(fillColor = "white",
              color = "black",
              weight = 0.5) %>%
  setView(-98.5795, 39.8282, zoom = 3)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

I added `states_shape_simple <- st_transform(states_shape_simple, 4326)` since I received a warning message by `leaflet` saying that the object `states_shape_simple` had an invalid datum. I don't know if you face the same warning message.

Anyway if you want to read something about the differences between `sf` and `sp` check Chapter 1 of [Geoocomputation with R](https://geocompr.robinlovelace.net/) (and maybe Chapter 6 about reprojections, such as `st_transform`). I don't know why it fails with `sp`, maybe you can ask to the [package mantainer](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rmapshaper/index.html).